# swift - Array error

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to reads records from a .txt file and store them as a collection of structs but I am struggling to fix this error:

```
"Missing argument for parameter 'year' in call
```

This is my code:

```
struct DataSet: CustomStringConvertible {

var year: Int
var month: Int
var tmax: Double
var tmin: Double
var airfrost: Int
var rain: Double
var sun: Double

var description: String {

    return "\(year) + \(month) + \(tmax) + \(tmin) + \(airfrost) + \(rain) +  \(sun)"

}
}


let path = "/Users/sc16hsm/Desktop/CW2/data/bradford.txt"

 var data = [DataSet]()
var temp = DataSet()

if let contents = try? String(contentsOfFile: path) {

let filtered = contents.components(separatedBy: "\n")

for line in filtered {
    let x = line.components(separatedBy: " ").filter{$0 != ""}

    let x = line.components(separatedBy: " ")

    temp.year = Int(x[0])
    temp.month = Int(x[1])
    temp.tmax = Double(x[2])
    temp.tmin = Double(x[3])
    temp.airfront = Int(x[4])
    temp.rain = Double(x[5])
    temp.sun = Double(x[6])
    data.append(temp)
    print(x)
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the members of the struct don't have initial values you have to use the memberwise initializer. The default initializer doesn't work.

You have to write **inside the loop**

```
   let temp = DataSet(year: Int(x[0])!,
                       month:  Int(x[1])!,
                       tmax:  Double(x[2])!,
                       tmin: Double(x[3])!,
                       airfrost: Int(x[4])!,
                       rain: Double(x[5])!,
                       sun: Double(x[6])!)
    data.append(temp)
```

Please use code completion to get the complete syntax.

Comment: Thank you but when I use this syntax I get a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Then one or more values can't be converted to `Int` or `Double` and you have to add optional bindings or the nil-coalescing operator to assign a default value. I have no clue what your text file contains. My snippet is just answering the question how to avoid the `missing argument` error. If you are using Swift 4 you are encouraged to use Property List or JSON format and the appropriate decoder.